Cannot resolve method 'regexMatcher' in 'HttpSecurity'
I'm trying to migrate this code to Spring Security 6:
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class NoFrameOptions extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.regexMatcher("^/.+$")
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable();
    }
}

new code:
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class NoFrameOptions {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.regexMatcher("^/.+$")
              .csrf().disable()
              .headers()
              .frameOptions().disable();
      return http.build();
    }
  }
}

I get Cannot resolve method 'regexMatcher' in 'HttpSecurity'. What should be used instead regexMatcher?

From Spring Security 6 on you'll have to use the #requestMatchers method of the configuration object of eg http#securityMatchers or http#authorizeHttpRequests and provide the specific matcher as argument:
  ...

  http.securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
      .requestMatchers(RegexRequestMatcher.regexMatcher("^/.+$")))
 
  ...

If you don't pass an explicit matcher but a string, Spring considers you to expect using an MvcRequestMatcher.

Do you know how I can migrate also .csrf().disable().headers()               .frameOptions().disable();?

.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable) and .headers(header -> header.frameOptions().disable())

For frameOptions() there is no replacement?

frameOptions is part of the headers configurer, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HeadersConfigurer.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#headers()

I get 'frameOptions()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal 

Not deprecated as part of the headers config.

Can you add please the complete code into the example. Maybe I'm wrong somewhere.

I'm currently not having any Spring Boot projects open to verify a 100% working example, you just have to adapt the old fluent API to the new customization objects, which provide then a fluent API for further configuration. See the two documentation links in the comment above, there you should get the idea of how to implement the frameOptions similar to the csrf example, like that: frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable)
